# React/redux child update child (<select> update <select>)

Tags: reactjs, redux

I have container, binded with connect() to my store.

```
// GetActiveAccount.jsx
const VisibleActiveAccountsList = connect(
    mapStateToProps,
    mapDispatchToProps
)(ActiveAccountsSelector)
```

ActiveAccountsSelector is the presentational component. Inside this presentational component I load two child presentational components which are only

```
    //activeAccountSelector render method
    return(
            <div>
                    <GatewaySelector gateways={gateways} onSelectGateway={ (e) => {
                            console.log(e.target.value);
                        }
                    }/>
                    <PairSelector gateway={gateways[0]} onSelectPair={ (e) => {
                            console.log(e.target.value);
                        }
                    }/>

            </div>
        )
```

What I want is that the selected value on gatewaySelector determine the value passed to PairSelector and update it when changed.

What is the right way to do that ? Going through actions seems way overkill for a simple select change update.

I guess I have to manager that in the parent (activeAccountSelector) but how ? It seems not advised to change state without going through the whole process (actions,reducers ...etc) shall I do that changing parents props ?

Comment: Probably not related to the question but you are missing the opening `<form>` tag.

Comment: thanks but not related indeed :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. You have to manage that in `state` of the parent component. Simply, you can change set the value for `gateway` property of PairSelector from parent's `state` and change the `state` when gateway change in GatewaySelector.

Redux suggest to using react state for the state that doesn't matter to the app globally. Read this [comment](https://github.com/reactjs/redux/issues/1287#issuecomment-175351978) from the Redux author for more information.

```
class ActiveAccountSelector extends React.Component{

  contructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = { selectedGateway: null};
    this.onSelectGateway = this.onSelectGateway.bind(this);
  }

  onSelectGateway(e){
    this.setState({ selectedGateway: e.target.value });
  }

  render(){}
    ....
    return(
      <div>
        <form>
          <GatewaySelector gateways={gateways} onSelectGateway={ this.onSelectGateway}
          }/>
          <PairSelector gateway={this.state.selectedGateway} onSelectPair={ (e) => {
            console.log(e.target.value);
          }}/>
          </form>
      </div>
    );
  }

}
```

Comment: I just realized redux is just not using react state O_O

Comment: may I ask why super(props) and not just super() ?

Comment: In this example, it doesn't matter to use `super(props)` or `super()`. But I usually prefer to use `super(props)` as it allows me to use `this.props` in the constructor.